# Is the assumption of linearity necessary for the convergence of the least squares method to the MSE solution

Tags: least-squares, convergence

More formally, say there are input vectors $\bf x$ and scalar outputs $Y$ being generated i.i.d. from a joint distribution $p$ and we are interested in estimating
$\mu({\bf x}) = {\mathbb E}_{p_{Y|{\bf x}}}[Y|{\bf x}]$ as a linear function of ${\bf x}$ as ${\bf w}'{\bf x}$.

MSE solution ${\bf w}_{\text{MSE}}$ can be found as follows:

${\bf w}_{\text{MSE}} = \arg\min_{\bf w} {\mathbb E}_{p}\left[ \left(Y - {\bf w}'{\bf x}\right)^2 \right] = \left({\mathbb E}_{p}\left[ {\bf x}{\bf x}' \right]\right)^{-1}{\mathbb E}_{p}\left[ Y {\bf x} \right]$.

The least-squares method is as follows:

${\bf \hat{w}}_{n} = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n {\bf x}_k {\bf x}_k' \right)^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k {\bf x}_k$.

(Problem formulation is done)

Now I think ${\bf \hat{w}}_{n}$ converges almost surely to ${\bf w}_{\text{MSE}}$ because $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n {\bf x}_k {\bf x}_k'$ converges almost surely to ${\mathbb E}_{p}\left[ {\bf x}{\bf x}' \right]$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k {\bf x}_k$ converges almost surely to ${\mathbb E}_{p}\left[ Y {\bf x} \right]$. It required no assumption of linearity such as

(1) $Y_k = {\bf w}_{\text{MSE}}'{\bf x}_k + \epsilon_k$, where ${\mathbb E}_p\left[{\bf x}\epsilon_k\right] = 0$ or

(2) $\mu({\bf x}) = {\bf w}_{\text{MSE}}'{\bf x}$.

However, all the proofs I have seen so far on the convergence of least-square methods, they require one form of linearity or the other. My question is do we really need this linearity assumption or there is a flaw in my proof above?

Now my hypothesis is that linearity of kind (1) is trivially true and hence is in line with my proof and does not in effect include an extra assumption. However, (2) is rather a bit more stricter assumption and hence not required for the convergence proof.

Answer (score 1):

The "flaw" in your proof, is that you have already assumed linearity by the way you have specified the objective function to be minimized.
The general statement for the minimization of mean squared error is (as it appears that you already know)

$$\min E[Y-f(\mathbf x)]^2$$
which gives the conditional expectation as the optimal solution $f^*(\mathbf x) = E(Y\mid \mathbf x)$, a function that can be highly non-linear.

*If* we restrict ourselves to *linear predictors* (or to linear *estimators of the conditional expectation*), then the least squares method is a strongly consistent estimator of the "projection coefficients". So, linearity is already assumed, and it is necessary for the least-squares projection to be optimal in MSE sense.

Looking at the end of your question, there is a fine point here: in the above procedure, we do not make any assumptions about the functional form/specification of $Y$, neither do we make an assumption about the functional form of the conditional expectation. So indeed, the two possible assumptions stated at the end of your question, *are not made*: The linearity assumption *is with respect to the structure of the predictor/estimator that we are going to use*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wouldn't say that assuming linear predictors is a flaw here because it is part of the problem stated in the first few sentences.

Comment: The important point here is that whether assuming linearity of the predictor implies any functional form on $Y$. It shouldn't, however, note that just assuming the predictor to be linear the assumption (1) becomes true. It sounds surprising, but it is not because having ${\mathbb E}_p[{\bf x}_k\epsilon_k]$ to be zero is trivial when the predictor is linear. If you look closely, it is simply another way of saying that the derivative of the MSE objective is zero at minimum.

Comment: Deciding on the form of an estimator/predictor has nothing to do with the specification of $Y$. It may be the case that $Y= g(x;w) + u$, and we nevertheless use the linear predictor $w'x$ -this cannot of course affect the true model. So I wouldn't say that adopting a linear predictor turns assumption (1) into the true model describing $Y$ -it is just a decomposition of $Y$ into two orthogonal components (which is useful of course).

Comment: I believe you do agree then that assumption (1) *is* true given the problem formulation.

Comment: I think we are essentially discussing semantics here. My point is that we do not _need_ to make this assumption, as an assumption on the true specification of $Y$, in order for the least-squares predictor to be used and be MSE-best in the linear class. So it depends on what is the "problem formulation" here. Do we start by specifying a model for $Y$ and then look for a predictor, or do we start directly by looking for a predictor for $Y$ remaining "agnostic" about its true structure? Both are legitimate approaches.

Comment: The latter. I have put "(Problem formulation is done)" in my question to indicate where the problem formulation ends. 

I am sure semantics is important. At the same time, I am also interested in knowing whether any of the assumptions directly follow from the formulation. I believe the assumption (1) does whereas (2) does not. 

The reason I care about it is because I have seen proofs that assume linearity of the predictor and mention assumption (1) as well. So I was wondering whether (1) was stronger than what the problem formulation already implies. I think you confirmed it does not.

Comment: Indeed (1) is not stronger, because it only asserts orthogonality between predictor and the prediction error which is a _result_ of least-squares prediction... and this is why assumption (2) does _not_ follow from the problem formulation, since it requires the stronger assumption $E( \epsilon \mid x) =0$ (which does not follow from least-squares prediction, and essentially it would be an assumption on the true structure of $Y$ being linear).